# Julia cannot match function method, seems it cannot tell ::Vector{Num}

Tags: types, julia

This is the function I wrote to use Symbolics.jl, where variables are of type `Num`.

```
function inverseDynamics(θs::Vector{T}, θ̇s::Vector{T}, θ̈s::Vector{T}, 
                         g::Vector{T}, Ftip::Vector{T}, Mlist::Vector{T}, 
                         Glist::Vector{T}, Slist::Vector{T}) where T <:Union{Int64, Float64, Num, Vector{Float64}, Matrix{Float64}}
```

However, in a call like this:

```
@variables θ₁ θ₂ θ₃ θ₄ θ₅ θ₆ θ₇
θs = [θ₁, θ₂, θ₃, θ₄, θ₅, θ₆, θ₇]
n = size(θs, 1)
M = Matrix{typeof(θs)}(undef, n, n)
θ̇s = [0 for i in 1:n]
θ̈s = [0 for i in 1:n]
θ̈s[1] = 1
M[:, 1] .= inverseDynamics(θs, θ̇s, θ̈s, [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], Mlist, Glist, Slist)
```

given declared variables of type `Num`:  `@variables θ₁ θ₂ θ₃ θ₄ θ₅ θ₆ θ₇` and `θs` is of type `Vector{Num}`,  and `θs = [θ₁, θ₂, θ₃, θ₄, θ₅, θ₆, θ₇]`

It gives me the error that no method is matching the call. And here is the exact erros:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching inverseDynamics(::Vector{Num}, ::Vector{Int64}, 
::Vector{Int64}, ::Vector{Int64}, ::Vector{Int64}, ::Vector{Matrix{Float64}},
::Vector{Matrix{Float64}}, ::Vector{Vector{Float64}})
```

```
Closest candidates are:
  inverseDynamics(::Vector{T}, !Matched::Vector{T}, !Matched::Vector{T},
!Matched::Vector{T}, !Matched::Vector{T}, !Matched::Vector{T}, !Matched::Vector{T},
!Matched::Vector{T}) where T<:Union{Float64, Int64, Num, VecOrMat{Float64}} 
at ~/Julia-scripts/symbolicDynamics/symbolicDynamics.jl:124
```

I am very new to Julia. I have been scratching my head but cannot find where went wrong. According to the closest candidates, only the first argument `θs` is a mismatch. I don't quite understand. Isn't `θs` a sub-type of the Union type in the function definition?

In addition, any Julia coding advice is welcome! Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your issue is that the function signature you provided uses the same `T` for all of its parameters, but the arguments you provide have different values of `T`. Here a simple example demonstrating the issue:

```
julia> function f(x::T, y::T) where T<:Union{Int,Float64}
       println("x is a $(typeof(x)) and y is a $(typeof(y))")
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(1, 2.0)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching f(::Int64, ::Float64)
Closest candidates are:
  f(::T, ::T) where T<:Union{Float64, Int64} at REPL[1]:1
...

julia> f(1, 2)
x is a Int64 and y is a Int64
```

As you can see, `x::T, y::T` does not merely mean "`typeof(x)` and `typeof(y)` each satisfy `<:Union{Int,Float64}`", but instead means the stronger condition "`x` and `y` are both of concrete type `T`, where `T` may be chosen to satisfy `T<:Union{Int,Float64}`". Once `T` is chosen, it can't be re-chosen.

In this toy example, the correct signature would be

```
julia> MyNum = Union{Int,Float64}
Union{Float64, Int64}

julia> function f(x::MyNum, y::MyNum)
       println("x is a $(typeof(x)) and y is a $(typeof(y))")
       end
f (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> f(1, 2.0)
x is a Int64 and y is a Float64
```

So for your own example you'd want to do

```
MyNum = Union{Int64, Float64, Num, Vector{Float64}, Matrix{Float64}}
function inverseDynamics(θs::Vector{<:MyNum}, θ̇s::Vector{<:MyNum}, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

> According to the closest candidates, only the first argument θs is a mismatch.

In this message:

```
Closest candidates are:
  inverseDynamics(::Vector{T}, !Matched::Vector{T}, !Matched::Vector{T},
!Matched::Vector{T}, !Matched::Vector{T}, !Matched::Vector{T}, !Matched::Vector{T},
!Matched::Vector{T}) where T<:Union{Float64, Int64, Num, VecOrMat{Float64}}
```

the `!Matched` refers to arguments whose types *didn't* match. So it's actually only the first argument that did match, and all the rest are mismatches.

When Julia encounters your call, it sees that your first argument is a `Vector{Num}`, so it attempts to match it with this method you've written for `inverseDynamics`, by fixing `T` to `Num`. So the first argument matches because `T` accepts `Num`. But then, none of the rest of the arguments can match, because none of them are of `Vector{Num}` type (and `T` is now fixed to `Num`).

To fix the issue, and for the sake of clarity and correctness, it would be best to just write out the actual types in place of `T`:

```
function inverseDynamics(θs::Vector{Num}, θ̇s::Vector{Float64}, θ̈s::Vector{Float64}, 
                         g::Vector{Int64}, Ftip::Vector{Int64}, Mlist::Vector{Matrix{Float64}}, 
                         Glist::Vector{Vector{Float64}}, Slist::Vector{Vector{Float64}})
```

I've made assumptions about which of the parameters you want to be floats and which ones int, and similarly about the vector and matrix ones. (That is what I meant by "clarity" above, since your existing method definition muddles these distinctions between the parameters.) But the general idea is that when you have specific, concrete types that you want to match on, you don't need type variables like `T`.

Comment: Thanks! You made it clear!  It is just I want the algorithm to take numerical values as well as symbolic variables, therefore need to specify a union of types.